# MySQL Version 8 Python 3.7 Cannot write None value as NULL

Tags: python, mysql

Previous version of code wrote fine with Python 2.7 to AWS MySQL Version 8 with the following:

---

> """INSERT INTO test_data(test_instance_testid,
> meas_time,
> data_type_name,
> value,
> corner_case,
> xmit,
> string_value)
> VALUES('15063', '2021-03-19 20:36:00', 'DL_chamber_temp', '23.4',
> 'None', 'None', 'None')"""

But now, porting to Python 3.7 to the same server I get this:

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: 'None' for column 'xmit' at row 1")

This makes sense since it is a str value 'None' and not Python type None (although it used to work).

It is legal to fill these columns as NULL values--that is their default in the test_data table.

If I change the code and set the values to Python None, I get a different error which I don't understand at all:

> """INSERT INTO test_data(test_instance_testid,
> meas_time,
> data_type_name,
> value,
> corner_case,
> xmit,
> string_value)
> VALUES('15063', '2021-03-19 20:36:00', 'DL_chamber_temp', '23.4',
> None, None, None)"""

> pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'")

I really appreciate any help or suggestions.
Thanks, Mike

**Thanks for the help! Yes, NULL does work**, but I'm stuck on how to handle value types on the fly within my method. Depending on the call I need to write a quoted value in one case and non-quoted NULL on others. For some reason my old code (illogically!) worked. I've tried everything I can think of without any luck.
Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: None is not a valid value in MySQL. Does `NULL` work instead?

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't work for python 2.7 either. 'None' is a string and you can't put it into Integer field.
anyway try this

```
"""INSERT INTO test_data(test_instance_testid,
meas_time, data_type_name, value, corner_case, xmit, string_value) VALUES('15063', '2021-03-19 20:36:00', 'DL_chamber_temp', '23.4', null, null, null)"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Very convoluted using this MySQL connector, but after some effort I got it to work--hopefully this can be useful to someone else as well...
To restate--why can't I pass a Python None and have it INSERTed as a MySQL NULL? All attempts failed - here's the one I think should work:

```
    testid = 15063
    meas_time = '2021-03-21 18:36:00'
    data_type = 'DL_chamber_temp'
    value = 33.4
    cc = None
    xmit = None
    str_val = None

    """INSERT INTO test_data(test_instance_testid,  
              meas_time,
              data_type_name,
              value,
              corner_case,
              xmit,
              string_value)
              VALUES({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})""".format(
        "'{}'".format(testid),
        "'{}'".format(meas_time),
        "'{}'".format(data_type),
        "'{}'".format(value),
        "'{}'".format(cc) if cc is not None else None,
        "'{}'".format(xmit) if xmit is not None else None,
        "'{}'".format(str_val) if str_val is not None else None)
```

Here's the error - why is a value bring interpreted as a column name?

- pymysql.err.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'")

So, I brute forced it using 'NULL'.

```
q = """INSERT INTO test_data(test_instance_testid,
          meas_time,
          data_type_name,
          value,
          corner_case,
          xmit,
          string_value)
          VALUES({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {})""".format(
    "'{}'".format(testid),
    "'{}'".format(meas_time),
    "'{}'".format(data_type),
    "'{}'".format(value),
    "'{}'".format(cc) if cc is not None else 'NULL',
    "'{}'".format(xmit) if xmit is not None  else 'NULL',
    "'{}'".format(str_val) if str_val is not None else 'NULL'
)
```

And here's the query printed before execution:

```
q = INSERT INTO test_data(test_instance_testid,
          meas_time,
          data_type_name,
          value,
          corner_case,
          xmit,
          string_value)
          VALUES('15063', '2021-03-21 18:36:00', 'DL_chamber_temp', '33.4', NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

make default value as `NULL` at PhpMyAdmin